# How can one subclass endpoints.ServiceException?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

The documentation mentions "subclassing endpoints.ServiceException" at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/exceptions. However, subclasses can't really express anything beyond a string message, "state" and http code.

For any application to have smarter exception handling, errors need to carry more than this.

How can one subclass the exception class, providing a custom message/state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to extend the payload, but you can customize the status code.

As is done in [`endpoints.api_exceptions`](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/endpoints/api_exceptions.py?r=344#34) for a `400` error:

```
import httplib
class BadRequestException(ServiceException):
  """Bad request exception that is mapped to a 400 response."""
  http_status = httplib.BAD_REQUEST
```

The current list (as of 5/8/2013) of status codes supported for errors are:

- `httplib.BAD_REQUEST`: 400
- `httplib.UNAUTHORIZED`: 401
- `httplib.FORBIDDEN`: 403
- `httplib.NOT_FOUND`: 404
- `httplib.CONFLICT`: 409
- `httplib.GONE`: 410
- `httplib.PRECONDITION_FAILED`: 412
- `httplib.REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE`: 413

and these status codes will be mapped to other codes:

- `httplib.PAYMENT_REQUIRED`: 402 mapped to 404
- `httplib.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED`: 405 mapped to 501
- `httplib.NOT_ACCEPTABLE`: 406 mapped to 404
- `httplib.PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED`: 407 mapped to 404
- `httplib.REQUEST_TIMEOUT`: 408 mapped to 503
- `httplib.LENGTH_REQUIRED`: 411 mapped to 404
- `httplib.REQUEST_URI_TOO_LONG`: 414 mapped to 404
- `httplib.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE`: 415 mapped to 404
- `httplib.REQUESTED_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE`: 416 mapped to 404
- `httplib.EXPECTATION_FAILED`: 417 mapped to 404

In addition if your response is a `message_types.VoidMessage` object, you will be able to send `204` no content response (`httplib.NO_CONTENT`).