# endpoints.ServiceException subclass returning 400 status code instead of 409

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

In the Cloud Endpoints [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/exceptions) for exception handling, it is recommended to subclass the `endpoints.ServiceException` class to provide a custom `http_status` for 409 Conflict errors.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16450227/2232750) to another question indicates that some of the supported status codes get mapped by Google's infrastructure to other status codes, but 409 isn't one of the mapped status codes.

Using the `ConflictException` class from the documentation:

```
import endpoints
import httplib

class ConflictException(endpoints.ServiceException):
    """Conflict exception that is mapped to a 409 response."""
    http_status = httplib.CONFLICT
```

When I raise the `ConflictException`:

```
@endpoints.method(request_message=apimodels.ClientMessage,
                  response_message=apimodels.ClientMessage,
                  name='insert',
                  path='/clients',
                  http_method='POST'
)
def insert(self, request):
    client = models.Client.get_by_id(request.client_code)
    if client:
        raise ConflictException('Entity with the id "%s" exists.' % request.client_code)

    ...
```

I'm getting a 400 Bad Request as the response:

```
400 Bad Request

Content-Length:  220
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:  Thu, 27 Feb 2014 16:11:36 GMT
Server:  Development/2.0

{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "message": "Entity with the id \"FOO\" exists.",
    "reason": "badRequest"
   }
  ],
  "message": "Entity with the id \"FOO\" exists."
 }
}
```

I'm getting the same 400 response code on both the local dev_appserver and deployed to App Engine (on 1.9.0).  Stepping into the App Engine ProtoRPC code, the following [line](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/wsgi/service.py?spec=svn390&r=390#184) appears to be mapping all `remote.ApplicationError` types to a 400 status code.

If I update the `endpoints.apiserving._ERROR_NAME_MAP` dict to add my custom `ConflictException` class, I'm able to return a 409 successfully:

```
import endpoints
import httplib
from endpoints.apiserving import _ERROR_NAME_MAP

class ConflictException(endpoints.ServiceException):
    """Conflict exception that is mapped to a 409 response."""
    http_status = httplib.CONFLICT


_ERROR_NAME_MAP[httplib.responses[ConflictException.http_status]] = ConflictException
```

**Is this the correct way to implement `endpoints.ServiceException` subclasses?**

Comment: I just posted the same question, albeit w/ less research done on my part: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26318221/635125. Should I leave it open since it is fresh and might get an answer? Better yet, Brian, have you filed a bug report?

Comment: I filed a bug: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11371

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug as according to the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11371) filed by Chris.